# How can I match 2 pieces of information from the same file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My main program is a Q&A game, and at the end I want to write the player's name and score to a file, and then display the highest score from the file to the user

The file writing part looks like this

```
def scores():
    #This is where all the scores are written
    file = open("test.txt", "w")
    file.write("Mary 200")
    file.write("\nJohn 500")
    file.write("\nAlex 300")
    file.close()

    #The content is now read from the file and split line by line
    file = open("test.txt", "r")
    content = file.read()
    content = content.split("\n").

    scoresList = []
    for i in content:
        name, score = i.split(" ")
        scoresList.append(eval(score))

    maxscore = max(scoresList)
```

Now I have the max score from the file, but how can I match it back up to "John" in order to display both the score and the name?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `eval()`.

Instead of this:

```
scoresList = []
for i in content:
    name, score = i.split(" ")
    scoresList.append(eval(score))
```

Do the following:

```
content = {name:int(score) for name, score in (item.split() for item in content)}
```

This creates a dictionary of the following form:

```
{'Mary': 200, 'Alex': 300, 'John': 500}
```

You can now display it in a sorted fashion:

```
for item in sorted(content, key=content.get):
    print(item, content.get(item))
```

This prints the names and scores from lowest to highest:

```
Mary 200
Alex 300
John 500
```

If you want it listed in descending order, specify `sorted(content, key=content.get, reverse=True)` for the sorting function.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use a list. Lists containing tuples automatically sort using the first element in the tuple. So, change your last couple lines to:

```
scoresList = []
for i in content:
    name, score = i.split(" ")
    scoresList.append(float(score), name))

scoresList.sort()
maxscore = scoresList[0]
```

NOTE: I don't remember which order it will sort it in, you may need to add `reverse=True` to the `sort()` parameters

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate on the sort() and reverse = True? I'm new to programming I haven't seen those before

Comment: Please don't use `eval()`, even if it was present in the question.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Why is eval so bad to use generally?

Comment: Because if the text file contains something like `Mary\n__import__('os').remove('C:\\explorer.exe')`, you'll have problems. If all you want to do is parse a string into a number, just use `int()` or `float()` rather than using a function that evaluates arbitrary code. You can research `eval` on Google for more information.

Comment: On top of being weak to security vulnerabilities, `eval` is also slow, given that it has to lex and then interpret whatever it gets, only to find out that's its really just some `str`s and `float`s. Basically, unless you're writing an interpreter, you have no bloody reason to use `eval`. My generic advice for python beginners is "forget about `eval`, `exec`, and `execfile`. They have their uses the language (mostly with metaprogramming), but you should not use them, lest you accidentally shoot yourself in the foot."